# SQL real limit/top function

Tags: sql

I have a question about LIMIT/TOP. As I understand before we get only rows from the limit, the whole table is processed.
so if I write *Select * from TABLE limit 2*, first the whole table is processed and then it is cut.
Is there a way to cut it before it gets processed? So for example "take 2 random rows". So then I don't query the whole table, but only a part of it.
I hope this question makes sense to you. I will appreciate your help!

Comment: The database engine will definitely not "process the whole table" if you ask it for 2 rows like that. If, on the other hand, you ask it to order the table, it will use an index, if possible. If no index has the sorting method you've chosen, then yes, an ordering step will be added. However, "give me the first two rows from the table, no order" will retrieve two matching rows, and then stop. "two random rows" is different. Make sure you know what you're asking for here, as different questions will have different answers.

Comment: It depends on the implementation, and you have tagged three different implementations (mysql, sql-server, google-bigquery). For example in the case of MySQL, the implementation has a number of optimizations to avoid scanning the whole table. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html for details.

Comment: Note also that using `LIMIT` or `TOP` (depending on your actual database) _without_ also using `ORDER BY` does not make much sense.

Comment: I've removed the tag spam, as how a database engine works can vary a lot depending on the product. Just tag the RDBMS you are *really" asking about

Answer (score 1):

In the execution plan tree a `LIMIT` node will stop processing the child nodes as soon as it's complete; i.e., when it receives the maximum number of rows from the child nodes (in your case 2 rows).

This will be very effective in terms of performance and response time if the child nodes are pipelined, reducing the cost drastically. For example:

```
select * from t limit 2;
```

If the child nodes are materialized then the subbranch will be entirely processed before limiting, and the cost and response time won't be significantly affected. For example:

```
select * from t order by rand() limit 2;
```

Comment: great! that was the answer I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `Limit` clause used select statement is used to restrict the number of rows returns from the result set, rather than fetching the whole set from table.

If you use `Select * from TABLE limit 2` it will give result set in random order. It better to used `Limit` clause with criteria so you can increase the performance on table.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE column_name >30  
ORDER BY column_name DESC  
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it _random_, it is more accurate to say non-deterministic.

Comment: oh, that would be a great news.
But I thought if it is ordered first, it means that the whole table is processed, no?